# Nuxt 3 `asyncData` function not working for fetching blog details

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I'm having an issue with the asyncData function in my Nuxt 3 application. I'm attempting to fetch and map blog details from my CMS but the function doesn't seem to be working as expected.

Here's the code for the asyncData function:

```
    export async function asyncData({ params }) {
        function getCustomDate(passedDate) {
            const date = new Date(passedDate);
            let year = date.getFullYear();
            const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
            let month = months[date.getMonth()];
            let dt = date.getDate();

            let newDate = `${dt} ${month}, ${year}`
            return newDate
        }

        var response = await client.getEntries({
            content_type: 'blog',
            'fields.slug': route.params.slug
        });
        let blog = response.items;

        blog = blog.map((item) => {
            let renderOptions = {
                renderNode: {
                    [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ENTRY]: (node, children) => {
                        if (node.data.target.sys.contentType.sys.id === "codeBlock") {
                            return `<pre>
                                <code>${node.data.target.fields.code}</code>
                            </pre>`;
                        }

                        if (node.data.target.sys.contentType.sys.id === "videoEmbed") {
                            return `<iframe
                                src='${node.data.target.fields.embedUrl}'
                                height='100%'
                                width='100%'
                                frameBorder='0'
                                scrolling='no'
                                title='${node.data.target.fields.title}'
                                allowFullScreen=true
                            />`;
                        }
                    },
                    [INLINES.HYPERLINK]: (node, next) => {
                        if (node.data.uri.includes("player.vimeo.com/video")) {
                            return `<div class="iframe-container">
                                <iframe
                                title="${next(node.content)}"
                                src="${node.data.uri}"
                                frameBorder='0'
                                allowFullScreen
                                ></iframe>
                            </div>`;
                        } else if (node.data.uri.includes("youtube.com/embed")) {
                            return `<div class="iframe-container">
                                <iframe
                                title="${next(node.content)}"
                                src="${node.data.uri}"
                                allow='accelerometer; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture'
                                frameBorder='0'
                                allowFullScreen
                                ></iframe>
                            </div>`;
                        } else {
                            return `<span class="color">
                            <a href="${node.data.uri}">${next(node.content)}</a>
                            </span>`;
                        }
                    },
                    [BLOCKS.EMBEDDED_ASSET]: (node, children) => {
                        return `<div class="content-img"><img
                            src="https:${node.data.target.fields.file.url}"
                            width='100%'
                            alt="${node.data.target.fields.description}"
                            /></div>`;
                    },
                },
            }

            const { id, createdAt } = item.sys;
            const { title, description } = item.fields;
            const featuredImage = item.fields.featuredImage.fields.file.url
            const content = item.fields.details;
            const details = documentToHtmlString(content, renderOptions)
            const customDate = getCustomDate(createdAt)

            return{
                id, title, featuredImage, description, details, createdAt, customDate
            }
        })
        return {
            blogDetails: blog
        };
    }
```

A few points to note:

I have the necessary dependencies (client, documentToHtmlString, BLOCKS, and INLINES) imported and available in my script.
The client.getEntries is a function to fetch data from my CMS and it works in other parts of my application.
The issue seems to lie in the async function itself, as the data is not getting populated.

Answer (score 0):

asyncData is a Nuxt reserved function. Which you should use actually.
Try to use nuxt's asyncData / useFetch for your problem. [Use Fetch - Nuxt Docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch).

I suggest looking at the examples and go from there.
Your Snippet looks kind of wild to a Vue/Nuxt Developer.